# Struct in Struct has no member

Tags: c, struct

Well this is my first post, I'm really sorry for what I'll do...
I have a problem and I need to hurry, what I'm doing wrong?
It's abut a "library" program about structures
I have to files: an header with this structures

```
#include <stdio.h>
//Strutture
struct Date{short day, month, year;};
enum genre{thriller, novel, fantasy, horror};

struct Book{char title[64];
    char writer[32];
    enum genre bookGenre;
    struct Date published;
    short inLibrary;
    short outLibrary;
    short id;
};
```

And then a c file, this file contains only definitions; the main will be in another .c file:

```
#include "mylib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

...

//To add new book
Book_t *newBook(){
Book_t *bPtr;
if ((bPtr = calloc(1,sizeof(Book_t))) == NULL){
    printf("I'm sorry, I couldn't reserve enough memory\n");
}
else{

...

//Book genre
    while(genreOk ==0){
        printf("Insert new book's genre(0=thriller, 1=novel, 2=fantasy, 3=horror): ");
        scanf("%d",&t);
        if(-1< t <4){
            (*bPtr).genre = t;
            genreOk =1;
        }
        else{
            printf("\nInapropriate genre, try again");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //Data libro
    while(dateOk ==0){
        printf("Insert new book's day of publish: ");
        scanf("%d", &dayT);
        printf("\nInsert new book's month of publish: ");
        scanf("%d", &monthT);
        printf("\nInsert new book's year of publish: ");
        scanf("%d", &yearT);

        dateOk = checkDate(dayT, monthT, yearT);
        if (dateOk == 1){
            (*bPtr).Date.day = dayT;
            (*bPtr).Date.month = monthT;
            (*bPtr).Date.year = yearT;
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
More messy code
```

When I try to compile using gcc -c mylib.c I get this error:

```
mylib.c: In function newBook:
mylib.c: error: 'Book_t {aka struct Book}' has no member named 'genre'
 (*bPtr).genre = t;
mylib.c: error: 'Book_t {aka struct Book}' has no member named 'Date'
 (*bPtr).Date.day = dayT;
mylib.c: error: 'Book_t {aka struct Book}' has no member named 'Date'
 (*bPtr).Date.month = monthT;
mylib.c: error: 'Book_t {aka struct Book}' has no member named 'Date'
 (*bPtr).Date.year = yearT;
```

I'm using Virtual Box with Ubuntu on a Windows 10 machine

Comment: You haven't declared `t`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow.  I appreciate you're in a hurry to solve your problems, but please read [Ask].  Particularly, see if you can limit the code you post to that which is relevant.  Sometimes, finding out what is relevant lets you solve the problem yourself.  As for your specific problem, here's a hint - the book structure has a member called `bookGenre`, not `genre`.

Comment: `(*bPtr).Date` doesn't exists...but `(*bPtr).published` does (same think for `genre`). Note that if it's urgent, SO is not necessarily the right channel, taking a good breath and thinking twice would help you much better.

Comment: Wow, this code could have been reduced to a very small portion of what it is in order to reproduce the problem. This is important because the more there is to read, the harder it can be to find the flaw and there will be fewer people willing to even look at it. Concise communication is an essential skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

1. You are confusing type names and identifier names. For example, in your `book` structure, the member name is `bookGenre`, and its type is `enum genre`. You access structure members by identifier, not by type. So instead of writing `(*book).genre`, you need to write `(*book).bookGenre`.
2. You haven't declared the variable `t` before your `scanf` call.
3. You could implement your genre validation loop using `do`, like this:

   ```
   enum genre input;
   do {
       printf("What is the genre?\n");
   } while (scanf("%d", &input) != 0 && input >= 0 && input <= 3);
   ```

   A `do` loop will execute at least once, because the condition is evaluated **after** the loop body is done. This makes sense here, since we first ask the user the question, and then check if he has entered a number (`scanf("%d", &input) != 0`) and that it is in the range `[0, 3]`. If the condition has not been satisfied, the user is asked the question again, and this will continue until the user types a valid genre. Notice how we read into an `enum genre` directly, and not into an `int`--this is because `int`s can be assigned to `enum`s implicitly, without any casts.

And by the way, you can access structure pointer members using `->`. For example, instead of `(*book).genre`, you can write `book->genre`.

Comment: What @JohnHascall I didn't copy your answer.

Comment: added third problem @Les

Answer (score 0):

`genre` and `Date` are the *types* of fields in the struct.
`bookGenre` and `published` are the *names* of fields in the struct.

So, for example, where you wrote:

```
  (*bPtr).Date.day = dayT;
```

this is correct:

```
  (*bPtr).published.day = dayT;
```

BTW, almost every uses `->` instead of `(* ).` because it is easier, faster, and simpler:

```
  bPtr->published.day = dayT;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, this:

```
if(-1< t <4) ...
```

will not work.
This:

```
int t;

if ( (-1 < t) && (t < 4) ) ...
```

will.